# how to insert in item() function a concatenated string from Mysql command

Tags: mysql, vb.net

this is my code

```
 Select Case activebarangay
        Case "Barangay Barangka"
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Exec("Select * from barangka_logbook")

            reader = ExecReader("Select family_number from barangka_patient_infomation")

            If reader.HasRows Then

                While reader.Read
                    familynumberComboBox.Items.Add(reader.Item("family_number"))
                End While
            End If

            'Member name
            reader = ExecReader("Select concat(first_name,' ',middle_name,' ',last_name) from barangka_patient_infomation WHERE family_number = '" & familynumberComboBox.Text & "' ")

            If reader.HasRows Then

                While reader.Read
                    membernameComboBox.Items.Add(reader.Item("concat(first_name,' ',middle_name,' ',last_name)"))
                End While
            End If
```

This what I'm talking about if is possible to put inside the Item() function a concatenated string:

```
 If reader.HasRows Then
     While reader.Read
         membernameComboBox.Items.Add(reader.Item("concat(first_name,' ',middle_name,' ',last_name)"))
     End While
```

how can it be? Please help me
                End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a field alias using the `as` keyword in the select list and use the alias to refer to the concatenated field:

```
       ...
       reader = ExecReader("Select concat(first_name,' ',middle_name,' ',last_name) as full_name from barangka_patient_infomation WHERE family_number = '" & familynumberComboBox.Text & "' ")

        If reader.HasRows Then

            While reader.Read
                familynumberComboBox.Items.Add(reader.Item("full_name"))
            End While
        End If
```